# contact form submitting error

Tags: php, javascript, validation, contacts

if anyone can just go through my code and find possible error, I've tried everything, but I just can't find mistake. My form validates just fine, but when it comes to submit and redirect to next page, it just reloads...

```
<?php
$your_email ='(i have removed e-mail)';

session_start();
$errors = '';
$name = '';
$visitor_email = '';
$user_message = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $name = $_POST['form-name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['form-email'];
    $subject_email = $_POST['form-subject'];
    $user_message = $_POST['form-message'];
    $user_id = $_POST['form-id'];
    $telephone = $_POST['form-telephone'];
    ///------------Do Validations-------------
    if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Morate popuniti polja ime i e-mail. ";   
    }
    if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
    {
        $errors .= "\n Pogresno unet e-mail!";
    }
    if(empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code'] ) ||
      strcasecmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_POST['6_letters_code']) != 0)
    {
    //Note: the captcha code is compared case insensitively.
    //if you want case sensitive match, update the check above to
    // strcmp()
        $errors .= "\n Verifikacioni kod je pogresno unet!";
    }

    if(empty($errors))
    {
        //send the email
        $to = $your_email;
        $subject = "Nova poruka: $subject_email";
        $from = $_POST['form-name'];
        $ip = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '';

        $body = "Posetilac $name je poslao poruku sa web-sajta:\n".
        "Ime: $name\n".
        "Email: $visitor_email \n".
        "Poruka: \n ".
        "$user_message\n".
        "Broj licne karte: $user_id\n".
        "Broj telefona: $telephone\n".
        "IP: $ip\n";

        $headers = "From: $from \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

        header('Location: slanje_uspesno.html');
    }
}

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" src="js/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
    <div id="container_header">
          <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container_kontakt">
    <div id="kontakt_email">
        <div id="kontakt_middle">

            <div id="forma">
                <div class="errors_kontakt">
                    <?php
                    if(!empty($errors)){
                    echo "<p class='err'>".nl2br($errors)."</p>";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div id='form_errorloc' class='err'></div>
                </div>
                <form id="form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
                    <ul id="form_list">
                        <li><label>Vaše ime:</label><input type="text" id="form-name" name="form-name" value='<?php echo htmlentities($name) ?>'/></li>
                        <li><label>Vaš e-mail:</label><input type="text" id="form-email" name="form-email" value='<?php echo htmlentities($visitor_email) ?>'/></li>
                        <li><label>Naziv poruke:</label><input type="text" id="form-subject" name="form-subject" /></li>
                        <li><label>Broj telefona:</label><input type="text" id="form-telephone" name="form-telephone" maxlength="12" /></li>
                        <li><label>Broj lične karte:</label><input type="text" id="form-id" name="form-id" maxlength="6" /></li>
                        <li><label>Vaša poruka:</label><textarea name="form-message"><?php echo htmlentities($user_message) ?></textarea></li>
                        <li><label for="6_letters_code">Verifikacioni broj:</label><img src="captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id='captchaimg' >&nbsp;<input id="6_letters_code" class="captcha_code" maxlength="6" name="6_letters_code" type="text" ></li>
                        <li><label>&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" id="submit" value="POŠALJI" class="submit"></li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
                <script language="JavaScript">
                    // Code for validating the form
                    // Visit http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml
                    // for details
                    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("form");
                    //remove the following two lines if you like error message box popups
                    frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplaySingleBox();
                    frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();

                    frmvalidator.addValidation("form-name","req","Unesite Vaše ime"); 
                    frmvalidator.addValidation("form-email","req","Unesite Vašu e-mail adresu"); 
                    frmvalidator.addValidation("form-email","email","Unesite validnu e-mail adresu"); 
                    frmvalidator.addValidation("form-id","req","Unesite Vaš broj lične karte");
                    frmvalidator.addValidation("form-telephone","req","Unesite Vaš broj telefona");
                    frmvalidator.addValidation("6_letters_code","req","Verifikacioni kod je pogresno unet");
                    </script>
                <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
                    function refreshCaptcha()
                    {
                        var img = document.images['captchaimg'];
                        img.src = img.src.substring(0,img.src.lastIndexOf("?"))+"?rand="+Math.random()*1000;
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any chance there is anything sent to the browser before the header redirect? You can use the `headers_sent` function to check right before your redirect. And is the mail being sent?

Comment: Yes, it seems the problem is the submit button, it doesn't have a name...

Comment: YOU SAVED MY LIFE!!! That was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if `$_POST['submit']` is ever submitted.  Looking at your code, it is never submitted as your submit button doesn't have a `name` attribute:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="POŠALJI" class="submit">
```

It needs to be:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="POŠALJI" class="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is your problem:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="POŠALJI" class="submit">
```

There is no input with the `name` attribute submit.

Change it to:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="POŠALJI" class="submit">
```